# How to filter a nested array with custom key in React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state value is

```
this.state = {
        staff: {
            ReserveCrew:{
                User:[{
                    id:'1',
                    name:'RC-FF-1',
                    user_type:'User',
                    resource:'ReserveCrew'
                },
                {
                    id:'2',
                    name:'RC-FF-2',
                    user_type:'User',
                    resource:'ReserveCrew'
                }],

                Superadmin:[{
                    id:'3',
                    name:'RC-SA-1',
                    user_type:'Superadmin',
                    resource:'ReserveCrew'
                },
                {
                    id:'4',
                    name:'RC-SA-2',
                    user_type:'Superadmin',
                    resource:'ReserveCrew'
                }]
            },

            Crew1:{
                User:[{
                    id:'5',
                    name:'C1-FF-1',
                    user_type:'User',
                    resource:'Crew1'
                },
                {
                    id:'6',
                    name:'C1-FF-2',
                    user_type:'User',
                    resource:'Crew1'
                }],

                Superadmin:[{
                    id:'7',
                    name:'C1-SA-1',
                    user_type:'Superadmin',
                    resource:'Crew1'
                },
                {
                    id:'8',
                    name:'C1-SA-2',
                    user_type:'Superadmin',
                    resource:'Crew1'
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have a function to change the user type and resource of a particular person with their ID. I'm trying to change the `user_type` to `User` and `resource` to `ReserveCrew` having `id=7` and save with the complete state value.

My handleChange function is

```
handleChange() {
    let staff = this.state.staff.filter((item) => {
        if(item.id == '7') {
            item.resource = 'ReserveCrew'
            item.user_type = 'User'
        }
        return item;
   });
   this.setState({ ...this.state, staff })
}
```

What changes should I do to get this working successfully for a nested array with custom keys?

Comment: Just a React hint, you don't need to use `...this.state` on `this.setState` you can write just `this.setState({ staff })`. React will merge the passed object with the actual state.

Comment: Error comes with filter function as the state is a nested array with custom keys

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't comment yet i'll post it here.

First when you do `this.state.staff.filter((item) => ......` it will only loop through the first layer so the `item` will be `ReserveCrew` and then `Crew1`.
Since `ReserveCrew` and `Crew1` is an object with a `User` and `Superadmin` it doesn't have an `id` property. So you should filter(loop through) each `User` and `Superadmin` for `ReserveCrew` and `Crew1`. This will make the code less readable.
In my opinion i would put all the users in an array since each user already defines wheter it is a superadmin or not and the same for resource;
so for example:

```
this.state = {
    staff: [
        {
            id:'1',
            name:'RC-FF-1',
            user_type:'User',
            resource:'ReserveCrew'
        },
        {
            id:'2',
            name:'RC-FF-2',
            user_type:'User',
            resource:'ReserveCrew'
        },
        {
            id:'3',
            name:'RC-SA-1',
            user_type:'Superadmin',
            resource:'ReserveCrew'
        },
        {
            id:'4',
            name:'RC-SA-2',
            user_type:'Superadmin',
            resource:'ReserveCrew'
        },
        {
            id:'5',
            name:'C1-FF-1',
            user_type:'User',
            resource:'Crew1'
        },
        {
            id:'6',
            name:'C1-FF-2',
            user_type:'User',
            resource:'Crew1'
        },
        {
            id:'7',
            name:'C1-SA-1',
            user_type:'Superadmin',
            resource:'Crew1'
        },
        {
            id:'8',
            name:'C1-SA-2',
            user_type:'Superadmin',
            resource:'Crew1'
        }
    ]
}
```

now if you want to change an user you can filter the `this.state.staff` with the same `handleChange()` function you got.

I hope you understand my broken english :)